# mutt seems to ignore EMAIL environment variable and .muttrc settings

Tags: linux, email, variables, environment, mutt

I just migrated from SUSE SLES9 (mutt-1.5.6i-64.6) to SUSE SLES11 (mutt-1.5.17-42.33.1). In SUSE SLES9 I was able to set the From: clause of mutt messages by instancing the environment variable EMAIL. Now I'm not be able to do that anymore. Moreover, event the settings in .muttrc ("set realname", "set from", "set use_from") are not working anymore. The From: header is always set to linuxuser@host.domain.tld. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you found the reason for this issue? I am suffering from the same, and the settings look alright.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, when used mutt command with sudo. In that case mutt will try to find .muttrc file under the /root directory, and if there is no such file, system user name will be used.